# How can I directly inject css into my index.html?

Tags: gulp, gulp-useref

I'm trying to concatenate external css and js files (that are referenced from my index.html file) and then putting them directly into my html file. I know how to concatenate and then put them into one single file. but haven't managed to write them directly into my index.html. If I use inject then it doesn't get the references from the index.html. I need to have as little files as possible for my project so i need to paste all of the code inside one html file. Anyone have an answer for me?

gulp code:

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){
    gulp.src(src/index.html)
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', modifyCssUrls({
          modify: function (url, filePath) {
            var splitted = url.split('/');
            return splitted[splitted.length - 1];
          },
          prepend: '',
          append: ''
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp'));
});
```

index.html before running gulp

```
<!-- css -->
<!--build:css main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../assets/css/shared.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!--build:js main.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../assets/js/fontfaceobserver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../assets/js/SplitText.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

index.html after running gulp

```
<!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

<script src="main.min.js"></script>
```

So I want it to actually paste the css into my html file like this:

```
<!-- css -->
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'circular-pro-black';
  src: url("circular-pro-black.woff2") format('woff2'),
         url("circular-pro-black.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'circular-pro-bold';
  src: url("circular-pro-bold.woff2") format('woff2'),
         url("circular-pro-bold.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'anchor-bold';
  src: url("anchor-bold.woff2") format('woff2'),
         url("anchor-bold.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'anchor-semibold';
  src: url("anchor-semibold.woff2") format('woff2'),
         url("anchor-semibold.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
</style>



<script>
and the js content here
</script>
```